# on Matrix Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $A=(a_{ij})$, and $B=(b_{ij})$ be two $n$ by $n$ real symmetric matrices such that
$$
a_{ij}\leq b_{ij}+\alpha, \quad \alpha>0.
$$

Can we conclude that $A\leq B +\textbf{1}\alpha$?

Note that $\alpha$ is a positive scalar, and $\textbf{1}$ denotes the matrix with all elements being $1$.

Comment: What I mean by $A \leq B+\textbf{1}\alpha$ is $B+\textbf{1}\alpha-A$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: This looks like quite straight forward inequality. But, there is something that bothers me, which actually I do not know what it is. I am unsure we can generalize the term-wise inequality to the matrix level.

Comment: Not every symmetric matrix with positive entries is positive definite.  For example, $$\pmatrix{1&10\\10&1}$$ is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: It might be of interest,  in view of searching/retrieving, to give this order relation its now current name "Loewner order".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\alpha=2$, $A=0$ and
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $0=a_{ij}\le b_{ij}+2$, but $B-A+I\alpha=B+2I$ is not positive semidefinite, because
$\det(B+2I)=-7<0$.